# Angular Directive inside d3 node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, tree

I've got a simple version of the tree layout (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) on my Angular app. However, I'm trying to replace the "text" node with an Angular Directive. How can I achieve this?

Instead of `.text(function(d) { return d.name; })`, I'm trying to compile a directive which takes in d.name as a parameter.

**VERSIONS**:

- *Angular*: 1.5.3
- *d3*: 3.5.17

Update:
The compile works great, it injects the HTML into it, however it doesn't show up in the SVG. When you hover over the `user-node` node in the DOM, it doesn't highlight anything on the page...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your questions a little vague but perhaps use a [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)?

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
  });

nodeEnter.each(function(d){
  var el = $compile( '<node-directive></node-directive>' )( scope );
  angular.element(this).append(el);
});
```

---

**EDITS**

I worked up an example.  It seems that SVG doesn't like the nesting of custom elements (your directives inside of it).  So, here's an approach:

```
nodeEnter.append("node-directive")
  .attr("data-name", function(d){
    return d.name;
  })
  .each(function(){
    $compile(this)(scope);
  });
```

Where `node-directive` is:

```
angular.module('d3Chart').directive('nodeDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var p = d3.select(element[0].parentNode);
        p.append("text")
          .text(attr.name);
        element.remove();
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Complete code:

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('d3Chart', []);

angular.module('d3Chart').controller('chartCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.treeData = [{
    "name": "TopLevel",
    "parent": "null",
    "value": 10,
    "type": "black",
    "level": "red",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Level 2A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "value": 15,
      "type": "grey",
      "level": "red",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Son of A",
        "parent": "Level 2 A",
        "value": 5,
        "type": "steelblue",
        "level": "orange"
      }, {
        "name": "Daughter of A",
        "parent": "Level 2 A",
        "value": 8,
        "type": "steelblue",
        "level": "red"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Level 2B",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "value": 10,
      "type": "grey",
      "level": "green"
    }]
  }];
});

angular.module('d3Chart').directive('nodeDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var p = d3.select(element[0].parentNode);
        p.append("text")
          .text(attr.name);
        element.remove();
      }
    };
  }
]);

angular.module('d3Chart').directive('treeLayout', ['$compile', 
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {

        var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 120,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 120
          },
          width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
          height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
          .size([height, width]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
          .projection(function(d) {
            return [d.y, d.x];
          });

        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        root = scope.data[0];

        update(root);

        function update(source) {

          // Compute the new tree layout.
          var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
            links = tree.links(nodes);

          // Normalize for fixed-depth.
          nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            d.y = d.depth * 180;
          });

          // Declare the nodes…
          var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function(d) {
              return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
            });

          // Enter the nodes.
          var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
            });

          nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d) {
              return d.value;
            })
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
              return d.type;
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              return d.level;
            });

          nodeEnter.append("node-directive")
            .attr("data-name", function(d){
              return d.name;
            })
            .each(function(){
              $compile(this)(scope);
            });

          // Declare the links…
          var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(links, function(d) {
              return d.target.id;
            });

          // Enter the links.
          link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
              return d.target.level;
            })
            .attr("d", diagonal);
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="d3Chart">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="chartCtrl">
      <tree-layout data="treeData"></tree-layout>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - that definitely helped get it on the page, but the node doesn't appear on the SVG at all. I've updated the original question with an explanation.

Comment: @Chronix3, what's in `md-menu`?  Looks like you are trying to freely mix HTML with SVG...

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tonight. The md-menu brings up a md-card as a tooltip and displays some basic HTML. Mainly <p> tags, an image and a ng-click to open a modal (outside of the SVG altogether)